# How to post the values of the checkboxes selected to WEBAPI from html form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core-webapi

HTML form :

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1.0">
        <h1>CAR SERVICE CENTRE</h1>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
    </head> 
    <body>

        <form name="CarServ" id="myForm">
            <div>
                <label>CarModel:</label>
                <input type="text" id="model" size="65" name="carmodel" placeholder="Enter Car Model" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Car Number:</label>
                <input type="text" size="65" id="num" name="carnum" placeholder="Enter Car Number" required >
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Contact number:</label>
                <input type="text" size="65" id="cnum" name="contactnum" placeholder="Enter your contact number" required>
            </div>
            <div id="service" class="opt">
                <label>Type of service:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="typeofservice" id="t1" value="Waterwash"required>
                <label for="t1">Waterwash</label>
                <input type="radio" name="typeofservice" id="t2" value="Fullservice" required>
                <label for="t1">Fullservice</label>
    
    
            </div>
            <br/>       

            <div class="check">
    
                <label for="checks">Addons:</label>
    
                <input type="checkbox" name ="checkk[]" value="10%off First service visit" id="10%off First service visit">
                <label for="10%off First service visit">10%off First service visit</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkk[]" value="10%off Waterwash"  id="10%off Waterwash">
                <label for="10%off Waterwash">10%off Waterwash</label>


                <input type="checkbox" name ="checkk[]" value="Free AC Inspection" id="Free AC Inspection">
                <label for="Free AC Inspection">Free AC Inspection</label>


            </div>  


    
            <div class="dropd">
                <label>Select State:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name ="selectstate" id="select1">
                        <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">--SELECT--</option>
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option1">Tamilnadu</option>
                        <option value="option2">Kerala</option>
                        <option value="option3">Karnataka</option>
                        <option value="option4">Maharastra</option>
                    </select>   
            </div>
            
            <div class="dropdcontent">
                <label>Select City:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name ="selectcity" id="select2">
                        <option value="option1">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option1">Chennai</option>
                        <option value="option1">Coimbatore</option>
                        <option value="option1">Madurai</option>
                        <option value="option2">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option2">Trivandrum</option>
                        <option value="option2">Kochi</option>
                        <option value="option2">Kollam</option>
                        <option value="option3">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option3">Bangalore</option>
                        <option value="option3">Mysore</option>
                        <option value="option4">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option4">Mumbai<option>
                        <option value="option4">Pune<option>
                  </select>     
            </div>
            <br/>
                
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <input type="reset" value="RESET" onclick="clearreset()" name="reset" />    
        
    
        </form>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="formtoapi.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

formtoapi.js : POST values from form to api

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit",submitForm);
function submitForm(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData=new FormData(event.target);
  formData.set("selectstate", $("#select1 option:selected").text());
  formData.set("selectcity", $("#select2 option:selected").text());


  fetch("http://localhost:5239/api/Forms/submit-form",{
    mode:"cors",
    method:"POST",
    body:formData
  })
  .then(response =>{
    if(!response.ok){
      throw new Error("HTTP error"+respsonse.status);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data=>{
    console.log("Success:",data);
  })
  .catch(error=>{
    console.error("Error:",error);
  });

}
```

Created a WebAPI and a controller FormsController.cs to post input values back to the console :

```
[HttpPost("submit-form")]
        public IActionResult SubmitForm([FromForm] FormsDataModel formsData)
        {
            // process the form data
            string carmodel = formsData.Carmodel;
            string carnum = formsData.Carnum;
            string contactnum = formsData.Contactnum;
            string typeofservice = formsData.Typeofservice;
            string checkk = formsData.Checkk;
            string selectstate = formsData.Selectstate;
            string selectcity = formsData.Selectcity;



            // validate the form data
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(carmodel) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(carnum) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contactnum) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(typeofservice) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectstate) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectcity))
            {
                return BadRequest(new { Message = " Enter the required fields." });
            }
            formsDataList.Add(formsData);


//            return Ok(new { Message = "Form submitted successfully." });
            return Ok(formsData);
```

Also created a FormDataModel:

```
namespace CarFormApi.Models
{
    public class FormsDataModel
    {
        public string Carmodel { get; set; }
        public string Carnum { get; set; }
        public string Contactnum { get; set; }
        public string Typeofservice { get; set; }
        public string Checkk { get; set; }
        public string Selectstate { get; set; }
        public string Selectcity { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Everything is working fine except those checkboxes. Actually I want to post all the marked checkboxes, but I'm only able to post only one/the first checkbox which I select. I'm able to select multiple of them but not able to post the values of all the checkboxes selected.
Can someone tell me how to make it happen, please help me understand what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will define a `List<checkk>` in the FormsDataModel Normally, but it will make the database more complex.
To make it simply as string.
You can add below code in js to set value of `formsdatamodel.chekk`

```
var checkstring="";
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkstring=checkstring+checkboxes[i].value+";"
}
formData.set("checkk",checkstring);
```

[image]
To get a list from string in api ,you can use

```
List<string> checkklist = formsdata.checkk.Split(';').ToList();
```

Comment: it worked! .Thanks a lot . I initially used array but this looks a lot satisfying.